# Is there a campaign wiki solution with mobile support?

Tags: tool-recommendation, mobile

I've been looking around for a campaign wiki for a [Dawn of Worlds](http://www.clanwebsite.org/games/games.html) game my group is in the middle of. I've looked at the usual sources ([Obsidian Portal](http://www.obsidianportal.com), [Epic Words](http://www.epicwords.com)), but they don't really have support for mobile browsers. As most of my 'net access lately is via Droid, mobile support is a major requirement.

Are there any hosted campaign wiki services that support mobile browsers? If not, are there any open-source wiki packages out there (with mobile browser support) that I could host myself? I'm not set on a wiki *per se*, so if you can think of any other way to have a multi-user-editable Dawn of Worlds game hosted online asynchronously (ie. not real-time) and have full mobile support, please post it. Ideally, this would include editing the map, too, but that's not a requirement.

**EDIT:** I've gone with [PMWiki](http://www.pmwiki.org). See my own answer below. I appreciate all of your answers; while in the end I didn't use any of them for this project, they gave me the additional insight I needed to reach a decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been testing [PMWiki](http://www.pmwiki.org) with [IPMWikiSkin](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/IPMWikiSkin). So far it seems to be doing exactly what I need, even if it is kind of weird seeing an iOS interface on a Droid.

Pros:

- Flexible handling of multiple users
- Handles mobile browsers
- Completely customizable

  - Can reskin, create custom markup, even change the code if needed
  - Has a repository of add-ons
- Self-hosted
- Can upload files with versioning

Cons:

- Self-hosted
- Not a turn-key solution
- Add-ons take some (minor) fiddling with the code
- Has its own markup syntax

  - That's one more thing for players to remember

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any hosted campaign wikis that support a mobile editing interface. However, there are a few wiki platforms that you could host yourself that are explicitly aimed at mobile support.

This [list of mobile wikis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_wiki) at Wikipedia would be a good place to start. I can't endorse any of them in particular since I haven't tried them, but wiki software is such a matter of taste that I'd encourage you to try a few regardless of whether I had a recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Not a wiki per se, but my group and I use Google Docs to handle this sort of thing for a PBeM campagin as most of our free time to read the posts is during commutes. I am not sure how the iPhone users feel about the ease of editing, but the droid user and the windows mobile user have no complaints for short entries and updates. For physical comfort, longer entries are better made from a full keyboard.

Most files we use tend to be spreadsheets just for ease of data entry and separation without the need for much formatting.

example:

- One spread sheet with all PC stats collated into one chart, and separate tabs for each PC individually
- One spread sheet with tabs to record rumours, plans, maps, theories, assets and resources, duty rosters, etc
- One spread sheet to detail specific items and equipment
- One Document with the ongoing campaign report

It is perhaps a less elegant solution than a wiki, but can be made to work very well in the environment you mention of doing most of your online work on a mobile platform.

Comment: I like this idea, especially since most of the group is used to Google Docs already.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Corkboard.me](http://corkboard.me) to augment a player Skyping in for our Alternity game.  [Here's ours specifically!](http://corkboard.me/YTjUU6AIzH)  They're working on a more mobile-native interface, but it might work depending on what mobile platform/browser you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do some customization, but I've had good results using a [Tiddlywiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TiddlyWiki) as a campaign wiki (check out [MPTW](http://mptw.tiddlyspot.com/) for some ideas on how to do particular things, or [Berin Kinsman's campaign wiki](http://berinkinsman.wordpress.com/downloads/) as an example) and it can certainly be viewed successfully on a iPad.

I haven't tried it with my Droid yet, but [the mobile wikis page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_wiki) claims that iTW is "a mobile version of TiddlyWiki" so I would think that was worth pursuing.

Comment: Most wikis can be *viewed* on a mobile, but few can comfortably be edited from one. And TW doesn't support multiple editors when published online, last I looked.

Comment: Depends a bit on your definition of "comfortable". TWs can certainly be viewed by many people at once, and there are locking add-ins. These allow each tiddler to be locked when being edited, to avoid collisions. Not clear whether multiple concurrent editing is part of the OP's requirements, but I wouldn't think so.

Comment: No, it doesn't need to support concurrent editing.