# What campaign wiki - or other collaborative tool - has these features?

Tags: campaign-development, tools

I saw the question ["Is there a campaign wiki with mobile support"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7672/is-there-a-campaign-wiki-solution-with-mobile-support) and realized that perhaps I could find what i was looking for with a more targeted question.

I am organizing a plot team (for a LARP) that recently moved from 3 people to 5 people (keeping only 2 of the original team) and I don't think our current solution is going to continue to be adequate. Right now, we are using:

- a set of forums for discussing plot-related issues. Currently a lot of our plot info is posted there, though it is not organized well. Examples of posts that should be here are "This is a concept I have" or "Here is a module I intend to run this weekend."
- a google group (email list for plot) that players can submit info to and that notifies the rest of plot when a response is sent. We discuss the issues internally (sometimes) and then copy the group with our response.
- a TikiWiki that has basic campaign information posted. For example, "this is an ongoing plot," or "this is a faction of people and these are their motivations," or "this is a city and here is information about it."
- a Dropbox folder that has a TON of information: PC character sheets, our monster and NPC stat-card database (in Excel with VBA), stat-card template documents, the most up-to-date version of our campaign map, dungeon write-ups, etcetera.
- a ton of hand-written notes
- a ton of PMs from the in-game forum (Small Machine Forums)

I would like to merge the information that we have in our current wiki with a lot of the info in our DropBox folder, our mailing list forum, discussions on our forums, and so on.

**This is what we need:**

- Good mobile support (Android, iOS) - both for reading and editing
- Support multiple users potentially attempting to edit the same page simultaneously
- Allow in-line image-posting, linking, thumbnails, downloading, and re-uploading
- Easily export or import the entire wiki (with or without file-system access; without is preferable but not required) so that I could download the page, edit it on-site (where we don't have internet) and then upload it again
- Allow in-line editing (no saying "oh hey you need to re-upload this page")
- Save login sessions and allow a user to login from multiple devices simultaneously
- Intuitive markup
- Discussion pages for wiki pages so that we don't have to use the wiki, skype, etcetera, to say "this doesn't look right."
- Version control - this is pretty standard among wikis...
- Minimal privacy controls (it needs to be hidden from people who aren't on plot; I don't need to prevent group A from viewing file C)
- An enforced hierarchical structure: TikiWiki does not have this.

**This is what I would like:**

- Simple image-editing - the ability to open an image that is linked on the site, save it and have it save the changes to the site version, if you choose.
- Even better than that would be [Integration with a map editor](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11120/what-collaborative-mapping-software-would-meet-my-needs)
- Ability to embed Word and Excel documents (with an appropriate plugin, if there is one) - this way we could get rid of our Dropbox dependency.
- Templates - for stat cards, which all have the same format.
- Printer mode for individual pages - specifically for the stat cards, mostly.
- Integration with a mailing list in a similar manner to the googlegroups interface - basically, someone can email plotteam@ourwiki.com and that generates a wiki-page on which plot can discuss the issue before responding. We already have this functionality and I could just link to the existing page, but if a place already has this functionality, all the better! I would rather use 1 tool than 2, assuming the same basic functionality.
- Easily set up on our own server

I looked into MonkeyPirate TiddlyWiki, but I got the impression while [reading the page that introduced it to me](http://www.encounteraday.com/2009/05/20/making-kickass-campaign-sites-with-mptw/) that it did not support the sort of collaboration tools, mobile browser support, or image editing integration that I was hoping for. I may be wrong - feel free to tell me so.

Comment: Have you looked at obsidian portal? You can make templates for lots of things, they have a shiny map feature and some other stuff. http://www.obsidianportal.com/. You could use Aviary for your images. http://www.aviary.com/.

Comment: I have not, but I will check out both of those.

Comment: @Cthos - I checked out Aviary and it does not seem like it has the features we need for image editing. I have not yet looked at Obsidian Portal in any depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently running a D&D campaign, and using an installation of [Dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki), which seems to fit most of the requirements on your list.

**Supports**

- Good mobile support (Android, iOS) - *We've used iOS for both quite a bit, and have at least one player using the site through Android.*
- Support multiple users potentially attempting to edit the same page simultaneously - *Has mutexes to keep multiple editors working at the same time - you can click the button, but it won't let you edit.*
- Allow in-line image-posting, linking, thumbnails, downloading, and re-uploading - **You can put images in line, link, make thumbnails, but I don't believe you can upload/download images from the text editor. It does have a built in media manager though**
- Easily export or import the entire wiki - *Data is stored in text files on the server, and there are [plugins](http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugins) that let you do this to some extent.*
- Allow in-line editing - *Yup.*
- Save login sessions and allow a user to login from multiple devices simultaneously - *Yup.*
- Intuitive markup - *Pretty close to Markdown, and you can get a plugin to make it use Markdown for real.*
- Discussion pages for wiki pages so that we don't have to use the wiki, skype, etcetera, to say "this doesn't look right." - *Yup - we use the [Monobook](http://www.dokuwiki.org/template%3amonobook) theme to make this much more useful.*
- Version control - this is pretty standard among wikis... - *Yup.*
- Minimal privacy controls - *Yup - has a full ACL system, which we use extensively. Groups, users, per-page, per-namespace.*
- An enforced hierarchical structure - *Yup.*
- Ability to embed Word and Excel documents (with an appropriate plugin, if there is one) - this way we could get rid of our Dropbox dependency. - *The Media Manager lets you upload files to the site, and you can link to them on pages. It doesn't let you embed them in the senes of being able to edit in line, however. We use this for PDF's quite a bit.*
- Printer mode for individual pages - specifically for the stat cards, mostly. - *At least available as part of the template we use.*
- Easily set up on our own server - *As far as I'm aware, all it takes is php. If you've got that, you're set as far as I know.*

**Doesn't Support/Not Sure About**

- Image editing - You can upload images, but I'm not aware of in-line image editing.
- Templates - this might be available as a [plugin](http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugins), but I haven't looked into it.
- Email to post - I've got no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Obsidian portal will work for some of your need and handles some of them really well. 
But I think too few of your wishes are granted. You will still need drop box and aviary and perhaps one more service.

In the end i don't think you will find any one service that provides all this, unless you have it developed for you, or buy a professional solution.

Obsidian portal does the following:

> - Good mobile support (Android, iOS) - both for reading and editing
> - Save login sessions and allow a user to login from multiple devices simultaneously
> - Intuitive markup
> - Discussion pages for wiki pages so that we don't have to use the wiki, skype, etcetera, to say "this doesn't look right."
> - Minimal privacy controls (it needs to be hidden from people who aren't on plot; I don't need to prevent group A from viewing file C)

I am a bit unclear of what this means "* An enforced hierarchical structure: TikiWiki does not have this."

Obsidian also have the following.

> - Templates - for stat cards, which all have the same format.

Not sure if this is an appropriate Stack Exchange answer, but it at least saves you the time to see what OP can and can't do

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out http://www.scabard.com.  You create a separate web page for each of your characters, groups, special items, places, and events; and then connect them with bi-directional links.  Example connections between two things in your campaign are "Father of", "Friend of", "Sub-region of", and many others.

It doesn't have everything you want, but has some of it.